# storing int values into array and getting average in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm trying to store integers into in array to add them and get their average
I'm not sure what's wrong (probably all of it) and I'm confused about the sw lw instructions, I'd appreciate some help, thank u

```
.data
array: .space 40
msg: .asciiz "Please enter 10 integer values:\n"

################# Code segment #####################
.text
.globl main
main: 

la $a0,msg 
li $v0,4
syscall

la $t2,array 

loop:
beq $t0,40 loop2 

li $v0,5 
syscall
sw $v0,($t2)

addi $t2,$t2, 4
addi $t0, $t0, 4
j loop


loop2:
beq $t0,0 end
lw $t1,($t2)
add $t3, $t3,$t1

subi $t2,$t2,4
subi $t0,$t0,4
j loop2

end:
li $t1,10
div $t3,$t1
mflo $a0 
li $v0,1 
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?  [mcve].  Single-step it in the debugger built-in to MARS or whatever, and look at register values.  IDK what you mean about `sw`.  It stores a word from a register to a memory location.  The manual documents what it does; can you be more specific about what you're wondering about it?

Comment: if i run it and i enter 1 to 10 integer values i get 163403687, yeah nvm the sw thing i was just confused about using addresses n stuff

Comment: Ok, but what do you see *with the debugger*.  I notice you don't init `$t0` before using it as a loop counter the first time, so make sure your array actually runs the right number of times, and that you're loading the right data in the 2nd loop.

Comment: yea thanks i initialized it now, turns out the problem was that $t2 register had the address 0x10010028 instead of 0x10010024 at the start of the lw loop

Comment: Ah right.  If you're going to save instructions by incrementing one way and decrementing the other, do the increment after the store, but the decrement before the load.  (And you can put a `bne` at the bottom of the loop where it belongs, instead of wasting a `j` instruction as well as an `beq`.  Also, you don't need 2 separate loop counters; you could put an end or start pointer in a register and compare against that.)

Comment: oh yeah thanks it works :)) (oh im just now reading the other stuff u wrote)